# Is there a way to transpose different column names

Tags: r

Is there a way to transpose dataframe with different column names FOr example

```
Col A   Col B
Table1  Date
Table1  Country
Table2  Name
Table2  Date
Table3  ID
Table3  Place
```

Required Output (Columns with same name should be aligned in the same column like Date)

```
Col A   Col1    Col2    Col3
Table1  Date    Country 
Table2  Date    Name    
Table3           ID    Place
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like to get the desired output you have to adress the cases where there is > 1 instance of a `ColB` value and the cases where there is only 1 separately.

Option 1:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, single := .N == 1L, ColB]
df[, b_id := frank(ColB, ties.method = 'dense')]

out <- 
  merge(
    dcast(df[single == F], ColA ~ b_id, value.var = 'ColB'),
    dcast(df[single == T], ColA ~ rowid(ColA), value.var = 'ColB'),
    by = 'ColA',
    all = T
  )

setnames(out, replace(paste0('Col', seq(0, ncol(out) - 1)), 1, names(out)[1]))

out
#      ColA Col1    Col2  Col3
# 1: Table1 Date Country  <NA>
# 2: Table2 Date    Name  <NA>
# 3: Table3 <NA>      ID Place
```

Option 2:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)    

df[, single := .N == 1L, ColB]
df[, b_id := 
       interaction(single, fifelse(single, rowid(ColA), frank(ColB, ties.method = 'dense')))]

dcast(df, ColA ~ paste0('Col', as.integer(b_id)), value.var = 'ColB')


#      ColA Col2 Col3    Col4
# 1: Table1 <NA> Date Country
# 2: Table2 Name Date    <NA>
# 3: Table3   ID <NA>   Place
```

Input data:

```
df <- fread('
ColA   ColB
Table1  Date
Table1  Country
Table2  Name
Table2  Date
Table3  ID
Table3  Place
')
```

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.